# How can I do a multiple route constraints in ASP.NET MVC Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

I have searched a lot on the internet to find out the way to make constraints like `The Customer Id should be a guid and required` so that I can end up with `[HttpGet("{customerId:guid|required}")]`, but unluckily don't have any solution to do like this. The document from Microsoft at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing, section **Route Constraint Reference** also doesn't shed light on this. Could anyone can do the multiple constraint values like what I just describe? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think it can be acheived by using `required` in route condition  `{customerId:required}` and in action you can specify type of incomming `customerId` like `Get([FromRoute]Guid customerId)`, later you can also check `ModelState.IsValid`

Comment: Where's the documentation for this?

Answer (score 5):

Simply separate the constraints with colons... `{customerId:guid:required}`. Constraints that take parameters are also easy to use in this way... `{id:int:range(100, 999)}`